# How can I use Proxys in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxies

So yeah My problem is that selenium dont want to connect with an proxy to the site.Why? (here my code)

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
uc.install()
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from termcolor import colored
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
def gather_proxy():
proxies = []
with open('Source/proxies.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        proxies.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
return proxies
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
proxiess = random.choice(gather_proxy())
try:
 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxiess)
 chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
     'credentials_enable_service': False,
     'profile': {
         'password_manager_enabled': False
     }})
 driver.get('https://www.wieistmeineip.de/')
 sleep(30)
```

So yeah can you help me? And yeah I have to add some more information so yeah here we go I guess xD

Comment: Have you gone through this? https://selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/http_proxies/

Comment: No. And thx for your help :D